# Retrieve a column from a table by comparing two different columns from different databases, using PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT image_name FROM image_uploader.image_base WHERE image_uploader.image_base.image_id != (select image_id from user_seen.{$value}_seen)
```

database structure:

```
Database ---------------> Table --------------> column
image_uploader ---------> image_base ---------> image_name
image_uploader ---------> image_base ---------> image_id
user_seen --------------> {$value}_seen ------> image_id
```

Code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT image_name FROM image_uploader.image_base WHERE image_uploader.image_base.image_id != (select image_id from user_seen.{$value}_seen)") or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $data["image_name"];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

I'm trying to use the above statement to to retrieve names(image_name) from table1(image_base) from the database1(image_uploader) by comparing the Id's(image_id) from table1 and table2({$value}_seen) and the names in table1 wont be returned if the Id's of that image are in present table2.

The above statement works only if there is only one entry in table2. When table 2 has more than two entries, the php returns -> `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

I need it to return the names which aren't present in `table2` in an array.

Comment: And is there any way to limit the number of results to a specific number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subquery returns more than 1 row, you shoud use `NOT IN` instead of `!=`:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT image_name FROM image_uploader.image_base WHERE image_uploader.image_base.image_id NOT IN (select image_id from user_seen.{$value}_seen)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: is there any way to limit the number of results to a specific number.

Comment: sure. you can use `LIMIT X` to get only first X rows